# Transfer data between JSPs. Data is received in one of the JSP's from the controller (SPring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to transfer data from JSP1 to JSP2. Data is being sent to JSP1 from Controller class (Spring MVC).

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("JSP1.jsp");
```

Data sent from Spring MVC Controller to JSP1

`model.addObject("documetIdentity", document.getDocumentIdentity());`

I want to call `JSP2` in `JSP1` and the data in `"documetIdentity"` is to be accessible in `JSP2`. I am using foreach on documetIdentity in JSP1.

Comment: Add it to the url or session ?

Comment: I tried adding it to the session and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

use ModelMap in your Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String helloWorld(ModelMap model) {

        String message = "Simplemente hola";
        model.addAttribute("msg", message);
        return "/welcome";
}
```

then in your JSP get the value

```
....
<div id="messageDiv" class="message primary"> ${msg} </div>
....
```

Maybe you want to make a validation

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(msg) > 0}">
    <div id="messageDiv" class="message primary"> ${msg} </div>
</c:if>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already able to get the value from Controller to JSP1. I want to loop through the value in JSP1 (sent from controller class) and send that value to JSP2  from JSP1.

Comment: Hi, humm ok, if you want to loop through the returned value in the JSP you should to use JSTL tag `<c:forEach></c:forEach>` for example and the result pass like an argument in the URL to the next JSP, something like this?. You are welcome!

Comment: Yeah something like that. Wanted to know how to implement it the argument of URL way.